# Fast DLNA sharing server

Tags: tv, media, dlna

I'm using AllShare software for my Samsung TV. The problem is, my media library is very large, and after adding something, Allshare PC application needs to be updated. Updates goes very slow: sometimes it takes even 30-40 minutes to update.

What I want to know is, is there any fast DLNA server alternative to AllShare that supports this kind of TV's and updates it's database faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [PS3 Media server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/) with my Samsung UN55D7000. I know it's meant for PS3 but I noticed it was in my sources one day, below the traditional inputs. I have been using it since then, it rarley locks my TV compared to Allshare. It also transcodes on the fly so you can watch MKV's, ISO's ect.

I know exactly what you are talking about though with the slow update time with Allshare I have about 2000 tvshows/movies and I don't notice any update delays when I add or remove things with PS3 Media server. I believe it is compatible with any DLNA device since my Google TV and Blu Ray player also see it.

Comment: The only problem is, I'm having issue with thumbnails: Video and pic thumbnails don't show

Comment: I know it's pretty great program... Not sure why it's not showing thumbnails. Do any images/videos show thumbnails?

Comment: No. It's not a big problem. Do you know, can I configure server to stream youtube channels? Will my TV support this plugins http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=9078 ??